# Как собрать android приложение с поддержкой java 8 из консоли (desugar)

Tags: java, android, lambda, classloader

Есть несколько классов. Они не используют API android-а и могут собраться java SE без зависимостей. В них используются **Lambda** и **Default  interface methods**.
В Android Studio они собираются, если в gradle файле модуля указать

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Теперь что бы собрать эти классы отдельно они переносятся в модуль IntelliJ IDEA.
IDEA собирает файлы и кладет их в папку out/production/ИмяМодуля.
Далее запускается команда

```
C:\AndroidSDK\build-tools\28.0.3\dx.bat --dex --min-sdk-version=15 --output=”name.dex" “out/production/ИмяМодуля”
```

Если в коде не использовать возможности java 8 то все работает.
Но если использовать лямбду, то при выполнении команды пишет

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncaught translation error: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: ERROR in ИмяКлассаИМетодаГдеИспользоваласьЛямбда:()V: invalid opcode ba - invokedynamic requires --min-sdk-version >= 26 (currently 15)
```

Если посмотреть на схему сбора Android Studio то там есть блок desugar.
[image: Java 8 language feature support using desugar bytecode transformations]
javac и dex работают правильно.
**Как desugar выполнить с консоли?** Вариант поднять min-sdk-version до 26 не подходит.
[Источник изображения](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support)